# Disable email syncing on public wifi

Tags: email, password, active-sync

I have a Samsung Galaxy S4 mini.
I have enabled active email syncing every 15 mintues cause it's obviously useful. However, I would like my password to remain safe when logged in to a public wifi that I may require temporarily when in a restaurant or airport. In other words, to suspend automatic syncing when using such unsafe networks ; sync only on trusted networks or when on roaming. Is there any way to configure that ?

Comment: Are you on public wifi a lot?  I would recommend using a VPN service, so turn that on when on public wifi then you won't have to worry about this.  As far as I know, there isn't a way to make the app only sync when connected to trusted wifi networks, unless there is an option for it in the app's Settings...?

Comment: No such option in the settings as far as I can see. As far as I know, VPN changes your IP and location. I assume from what you say that it also encrypts data, is that correct ?

Comment: It will create a secure encrypted connection between your device and the server you are connected to, and send all network traffic in this protected manner.  Your IP and location will change based on the VPN service you use/where you are connecting.  I use ExpressVPN personally, but there are many other services out there.